# Error in encapsulates filters (Q)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

If I have the next code:

```
class A(models.Model):

   .....

class B(models.Model):

    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

The next queries get differents results:

```
B.objects.exclude(a__in=[7])

from django.db.models import Q
B.objects.exclude(Q(a__in=[7]))
```

Results:

- The first query get all objects excluding the "b objects" with a=7. It's Ok
- But the second query get all objects excluding the "b objects" with a=7 or a=None.

Is it an error?, Is it known?

I add a verbose example, execute the next code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
u1 = User.objects.create(username='u1')
u2 = User.objects.create(username='u2')
u3 = User.objects.create(username='u3')
g1 = Group.objects.create(name='g1')
g2 = Group.objects.create(name='g2')
u1.groups.add(g1)
u2.groups.add(g2)
print User.objects.exclude(groups__in=[g1.pk])
print User.objects.exclude(Q(groups__in=[g1.pk]))
```

Comment: You're almost certainly not trying to actually use just `B.objects.exclude(Q(a__in=[7]))`. Most likely the actual query has something in it that's resulting in this behavior. I think you've oversimplified your examples here. Try posting code more akin to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is fixed in Django:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17600

This was a django bug

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure i'd call it an "error", but the two versions do send unique queries (Django 1.3.1).

Without `Q`:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
FROM "auth_user"
WHERE NOT ("auth_user"."id" IN
             (SELECT U1."user_id"
              FROM "auth_user_groups" U1
              WHERE (U1."group_id" IN (2)
                     AND U1."user_id" IS NOT NULL)))
```

With `Q`:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
FROM "auth_user"
INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."user_id")
WHERE NOT ("auth_user_groups"."group_id" IN (2))
```

What's interesting is that if you use `filter` instead of `exclude`, they both send exactly the same query. Nevertheless, this may actually be intentional. `Q` is never really used by itself (there's no point), so the query is probably pre-optimized for additional AND/OR/NOT relations. Whereas, the version without `Q` is done, for all intents and purposes. If you really have a problem with this behavior, you can file a ticket, but I'd say just don't use `Q` when you only have one.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I vote your answer for it. I know that with filter works. The query is only a example, obviously it is a nonsense use Q when you only have one lookup. You can change the last query to this User.objects.exclude(Q(groups__in=[g1.pk])|Q(username='u2'). I created a ticket code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17600